# Understanding how to obtain homotopy from a picture.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose that we are given two paths $f:I\to X$ and $f^{-1}(t):=f(1-t)$. Let $c_p$ be the constant map at $p\in X$. It is to be proven that $c_p\simeq f\circ f^{-1}$, where $\circ$ represents concatenation of paths.

The book gives the following diagram.

[image]

Then somehow concludes from it that the desired Homotopy is:

$H(s,t):=\begin{cases}f(2s); & 0\le s\le t/2 \\
f(t); & t/2\le s\le 1-\frac t2\\
f(2-2s); & 1-\frac t2\le s\le 1 \end{cases}$

I don't understand how this $H$ is obtained using the picture. I don't even understand why this $H$ is the desired homotopy: I know that $H$ is continuous by pasting lemma, and that $H(_,0)=f(0), H(_,1)= ?$. Can anyone please help me understand how to get homotopy using the picture?

I also want to add that I am sure that I will find the homotopy from various sources but it will be like- 'Define H like this and verify that this works'. But I'm not looking for that. I'm looking for a way to construct the homotopy using picture. Can anyone please help me understand that? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Your homotopy is constant along each thin horizontal/vertical line.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Thanks for the comment! Yes, it is constant there but how did they write f(2s)? Where does 2s come from? And where does 2-2s come from?

Comment: Think of graphs of some linear functions that you see on the picture.

Comment: @MoisheKohan The tilted lines are t=2s and t=2-2s so don't understand why it is **not** f(2s/t) for $s\le t/2$.

Comment: I have a similar (but not duplicate question) [here] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4641424/constructing-a-homotopy-in-a-square) also. I don't know what I'm missing. Can anyone please help me understand this? Thanks.

Comment: Try your suggestion and see if it works; in particular, is it constant on vertical lines.

Comment: It is not a constant on the vertical lines so my suggestion doesn't work (as it is not in line with the picture) but how was the specific quantity 2s located? What was the process behind it? Why not 1.5 s instead of 2s?

Comment: Ohh, I think it is like this: Take a point (s, t) for s<=t/2. Then the vertical line through (s, t) meets the line t=2s at (s, 2s). Since H is constant on the vertical line, we should have H(s, t) = f(2s).

Comment: But this looks wrong so I'm not sure.

Comment: What's the reason you think it looks wrong? It is actually correct.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I don't know what I was thinking. I understand now that it is correct. Thank you! Could you please also advice as to how I can answer my other question (linked earlier)?

Answer (score 1):

The picture wants to say that for each $r \in [0,1]$ the desired homotopy $H$ is constant on each polygonal chain $C_r$ consisting of the three line segments $a_r$ going from $(\frac r 2,1)$ to $(\frac r 2,r)$, $b_r$ going from $(\frac r 2,r)$ to $(1-\frac r 2 ,r)$ and $c_r$ going from $(1-\frac r 2,r)$ to $(1-\frac r 2,1)$. These line segments have length $1- r$ and are three edges of a square.

We have $a_r = \{(\frac r 2,y) \mid r \le y \le 1 \}$, $b_r = \{ (s,r) \mid \frac r 2 \le s \le 1 -\frac r 2 \}$ and $c_r = \{(1- \frac r 2,y) \mid r \le y \le 1 \}$.

Thus on $b_t$ the homotopy has to take the value $(f \circ f^{-1})(\frac t 2) = f(2 \frac t 2) = f(t)$ which agrees with $(f \circ f^{-1})(1-\frac t 2) = f^{-1}(2(1- \frac t 2) -1) = f^{-1}(1-t) = f(t)$. Therefore
$$H(s,t) = f(t) \text{ for }  \frac t 2 \le s \le 1 - \frac t 2 .$$

On $a_r$ the homotopy has to take the value $(f \circ f^{-1})(\frac r 2) = f(r)$. The triangle $T_l$ with vertices $(0,0), (0,1), (\frac 1 2, 1)$ is the set of points $(s,t) \in [0,1]^2$ with $0 \le s \le \frac t 2$. Each $(s,t) \in T_l$ lies on a unique $a_r$; clearly we have $r = 2s$. Therefore
$$H(s,t) = f(2s) \text{ for } 0 \le s \le \frac t 2 .$$

On $c_r$ the homotopy has to take the value $(f \circ f^{-1})(1- \frac r 2) = f(r)$. The triangle $T_r$ with vertices $(0,1), (1,1), (\frac 1 2, 1)$ is the set of points $(s,t) \in [0,1]^2$ with $1 - \frac t 2 \le s \le 1$. Each $(s,t) \in T_r$ lies on a unique $c_r$; clearly we have $r = 2(1-s)$. Therefore
$$H(s,t) = f(2(1-s)) \text{ for } 1 -\frac t 2  \le s \le 1 .$$

By picture and formal definition we get for all $s \in [0,1]$
$$H(s,0) = f(0) = p ,$$
$$H(s,1) = (f \circ f^{-1})(s) .$$